# dottrace async await support is not working

Tags: async-await, profiling, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

Jetbrains's dottrace should have profiling support for async/await.

But I cannot get it to show me the expected results (I have no "await" and "continuation" nodes in the timelineviewer call stack).

I tried profiling with the following program types:

- .NET framework (4.7) console program,
- .NET framework (4.7) windows program,
- .NET core (>2.2) console,
- .NET core (>2.2)windows program,
- .NET core (3.0) wpf

Is this only not working for me ? Because I cannot find anything on the internet
or is this officially currently not working anymore ?

My only reference to possible explaination is for console applications:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DTRC-26464
Something about :

AsyncCausalityTracer.LoggingOn being false and some ETW provider.
But for me this is not working, for all type of applications

My current version of jetbrains software is :
Resharper Ultimate 2019.2.3 (dottrace 2019.2)

--- EDIT 2019/11/01:

When clicking on events I get (I would expect also TPL events ???):
[image: types of events]

--- EDIT 2019/11/06:

As a result of a comment in answer from Konkat [info link](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26333), I also tried :

- .NET core 2.0 console application

=> dottrace async support also does not work

Answer (score 0):

Is the "Collect TPL events" option enabled in your configuration? [image]

Comment: Yes indeed this is enabled

Comment: I see. For .NET Core 2.1 or later "await" and "continuations" nodes in call tree are missed because of the following issue in CoreCLR: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26333

Comment: For console .NET Framework 4.7 application they are missed because of  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DTRC-26464.
However, they must be presented for .NET Framework 4.7 WPF application. Are you sure that there are no these nodes in the call tree in this case?
About the Events table - no, dotTrace doesn't show TPL events in this table.

Comment: I edited the question as response to comment two about the .NET core. Summary is that even for  core 2.0 it is not working. I assume that a version e.g. 2.0 never gets any updates after being released. So not sure why it is not working then.